# Extra dash insertion when trying to run tar

Tags: bash

I have a really weird issue where I'm getting an extra `-` insertion on tar:

```
# tar -zxvf mod_wsgi-3.3.tar.gz 
/bin/tar: unrecognized option '--zxvf'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

The same issue happens if I try to do --help

```
# tar --help
/bin/tar: unrecognized option `---help'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

But if I drop the first `-` both of the above examples work. Any ideas on how I can find and disable whatever is causing that?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Interesting.  I always run tar without the dash : `tar xvfz blah` .

Comment: @Kit, and what version of tar ?

Comment: @Lekensteyn A really bare version of 10.04 as supplied with my VPS. I've had to install just about everything myself. @jgbelacqua - 1.22

Comment: @jgbelacqua: me too, but that is only allowed as first argument, so if you need to supply a different extraction dir, you would do something like `tar xf file.tar.gz -C /target`.

Comment: @Kit Sunde: can you follow peopluan's instructions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect there's an alias or function mangling your tar.

Post the output of `alias | grep tar` and `set | grep -E "function tar|tar \(\)"`

(I know I should leave a comment, but I don't have enough rep-point for commenting, yet)

Edit: Also, post the output of `which tar` please.

Comment: It actually makes sense as answer, but I could not reproduce it with an alias as in `alias tar='tar -'`.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Indeed. The space after the aliased tar possibly renders the additional dash ineffective. So I've edited my 'answer' to check out for a 'tar' script somewhere in the system.

Comment: AHA, `which tar` says my tar is in `/usr/local/sbin/tar`! I had worked around another issue where tar was failing on some permission bug and someone on ubuntuforums suggested adding a user defined tar, and then running dist-upgrade to solve it. However I had forgotten to remove it (twice!). http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10366526&postcount=4

Comment: `type -a tar` will give all the information you were trying to collect with those commands. `help type`.