# apt-get fails with: "cannot utime"

Tags: apt

I have an issue where [apt-get](/questions/tagged/apt-get) fails with the error message "Cannot utime":

```
tar: ./postinst: Cannot utime: Bad file descriptor
tar: ./preinst: Cannot utime: Bad file descriptor
tar: ./prerm: Cannot utime: Bad file descriptor
tar: ./md5sums: Cannot utime: Bad file descriptor
tar: ./control: Cannot utime: Bad file descriptor
tar: .: Cannot utime: Bad file descriptor
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
dpkg-deb: subprocess tar returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-mpm-prefork_2.2.14-5ubuntu8.4_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-mpm-prefork_2.2.14-5ubuntu8.4_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This seem to be related to [tar](/questions/tagged/tar) as if I follow the [instructions in a post on ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10366526&postcount=4) and create a user defined [tar](/questions/tagged/tar) `/usr/local/sbin/tar` the error stops happening.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /bin/tar --touch -"$@"
```

However that solution caused me to ask a question about [Extra dash insertion when trying to run tar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35266/extra-dash-insertion-when-trying-to-run-tar) I would much prefer to just have regular tar working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real problem is bug [LP #539814](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tar/+bug/539814). The solution is to upgrade your kernel or use a patched tar program.

Otherwise, use the next workaround:
Replace the contents of the `/usr/local/sbin/tar` file with:

```
#!/bin/sh
TAR_OPTIONS="--touch $TAR_OPTIONS" /bin/tar "$@"
```